# Java: how create instance having the "Class" object?

Tags: java, class, generics

Good day,

within a class a have a "Class" type data member which I initialize in constructor. Then I would like to create objects (instances) of this class. How to do it?

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class runMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        String testStr = "XXX";
        testClass cls = new testClass(testStr.getClass());
        cls.createInstance();
    }
}

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class testClass {
    Class<?> myClass;

    testClass(Class inputClass) {
        this.myClass = inputClass;
    }

    void createInstance() throws NoSuchMethodException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        myClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // this works
       //QUESTION, how to do something like this (and return, in this example a String):
       myClass anInstance = myClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `anInstance` variable needs to have either the correct type or the type of least speficic superclass, which is `Object`. You need to take a look at generics.

Comment: "Object" solved my problem. Maybe it is bad practice but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to make your `testClass` class generic. You can use a type parameter as the data type of `anInstance` and as the type argument for your `inputClass` class type:

```
class testClass<T> {
    Class<T> myClass;

    testClass(Class<T> inputClass) {
        this.myClass = inputClass;
    }

    void createInstance() throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, 
                IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        T anInstance = myClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}
```

It's likely that you want to restrict `T` to certain types, so you probably want to make it bounded too.